# UITextField beginningOfDocument property returning nil

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios8.3

I have created a `UITextField` programatically. Now when I try to get its `beginningOfDocument` property, it is becoming `nil`.

Code is as follows:

```
public func addTextField(title:String?=nil) -> UITextField {
    kWindowHeight -= 80.0
    let txt: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 13, y: 67, width: 213.00, height: 35));
    txt.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    txt.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    txt.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x1E8ADB).CGColor
    txt.font = UIFont(name: kDefaultFont, size: 14)
    txt.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Words
    txt.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
    txt.layer.masksToBounds = true
    txt.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    if title != nil  {
        txt.placeholder = title!
    }
    contentView.addSubview(txt)

    return txt
}
```

In some other class I am calling:

```
let textField = AlertView().addTextField("Send SMS")
var begining = textField.beginingOfDocument
```

Comment: Show me your code please

Comment: What is `textField.beginingOfDocument` - not a UITextField property!? What is `AlertView`? what does `addTextField` do?

Comment: Ah, it is a property of `UITextInput`...

Comment: Note, COPY code from xcode and poste it her, dont rephrase the code, there is no `beginingOfDocument`, only `beginningOfDocument`!

Comment: @luk2302: Thanks..I will keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you merely create an UITextField then immediately try to access `beginningOfDocument` property OR even after trying to add it to a superview, you will always get an `uninitialized` value.

Try to retrieve that property after the UITextField becomes the first responder and see the result :-)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks....I have upvoted but having since less than 15 points The upvote is not getting increased.